# readingJSON with simplejson python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, urllib2

i'm trying to read JSON after i'm sending url request with urllib2.

my code:

```
request = urllib2.Request("https://127.0.0.1:443/myAPI", data=form_data, headers=headers)
response = urllib2.open(request)
```

So the problem is when i'm trying to read to JSON from the respond object.
i'm doing it like that

```
 simplejson.loads(response.read())
```

the error i get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/new/main3/python/simplejson/__init__.py", line 385, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/opt/new/main3/python/simplejson/decoder.py", line 402, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/opt/new/main3/python/simplejson/decoder.py", line 420, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("No JSON object could be decoded", s, idx)
simplejson.decoder.JSONDecodeError: No JSON object could be decoded: line 1 column 0 (char 0)
```

The **interesting** part is when i'm sending the request in my firefox browser, I'm typing the address *127.0.0.1/myAPI* at the url line , i do get the json on screen and i can see it at the debug mode as a JSON
    {"hosts": [{"host": "127.0.0.1:4448"}]}

so the json is valid..

at the debug i'm getting this page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- framebusting -->
    <style>
        html{display : none ;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (self == top) {
            document.documentElement.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            top.location = self.location;
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/detectBrowser.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="css/forensics.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/requirejs/require.js" data-main="js/login.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

is any one have some way to solve it , or how can i read the json text straight from the respond object , or even look at that at the debug

I appreciate ant help , i'm trying for the least 3 days to figure it out 
Thanks

Comment: Try to print what is the response to check that it is the same that with the browser by doing `print response.read()'` and post the result here. It is also possible that the returned strings has some invisible control character that your browser doesn't display but make simplejson fails.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- framebusting -->
    <style>
        html{display : none ;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (self == top) {
            document.documentElement.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            top.location = self.location;
        }

Comment: </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/detectBrowser.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="css/forensics.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/requirejs/require.js" data-main="js/login.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: haha, voilà ! So you get some HTML instead. Check your request  (header, data or data placement)!

Comment: sorry but i post it in 2 comment cause is to long .

Comment: Post it in the question...

Comment: first thanks , but what do you mean?. i didn't use any header/data in both cases. how can i know which header the browser is adding to the request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128956/discussion-between-antoine-and-yntnm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it was my bad and the api was need a coockie.
after adding a cookie header i was receiving a correct JSON

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of this  `simplejson.loads(response .read())`. You have a space between response and .read()

Try the following:

```
request = urllib2.Request("https://127.0.0.1:443/myAPI", data=form_data, headers=headers)
response = urllib2.open(request) 
response_body = response.read()
response_body_json = simplejson.loads(response_body)
```

Comment: no... in the real code i don't have. and i fix it here also